# CSS max-width with percent

Tags: html, css

max-width with a percent doesn't seem to work in either IE 8 or Firefox 3. Specific pixel widths work fine. Am I missing something?

I have an input form, and I want to display some explanatory text to the right of it. But I don't want the explanatory text to squash the form.

I haven't used max-width before but it seemed an excellent solution. I wrote this simple CSS style:

```
div.hint {max-width: 50%; float: right;}
```

Then I wrote:

```
<div class=hint>... hint text</div>
<form action=xxx method=post>
... etc ...
```

The div.hint squashes the form severely to the left.

I tried this with just some text instead of the form. The div.hint takes about 95% of the screen, just gives a small margin on the left, and then the other text is pushed completely below it.

If I change the max-width from a percent to a fixed number of pixels, it appears to work. But I don't want to base it on pixels because I don't know the dimensions of the user's browser.

Does percent not work with max-width despite what I read in documentation, or am I missing something?

---

In response to Seanmonster's comment: Here, I'll give a trivial but complete web page that illustrates what I thought should work but doesn't:

```
<html><title>Max width test</title>
<style>
.form {max-width: 75%; float: left;}
.hint {max-width: 50%; float: right;}
</style>

<div class=hint>
<p>Fourscore and seven years ago our forefathers brought forth on this continent a new nation, conceived in liberty and dedicated to the proposition that
all men are created equal. We are now engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived and so dedicated,
can long endure. We are met on a great battlefield of that war. We have come to dedicate a portion of that field as a final resting place
for those who here gave their lives that that nation might live. It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this. Etc.
</div>
<div class=form>
<table>
<tr><th>Label 1 <td>Value 1
<tr><th>Label 2 <td>Value 2
<tr><th>Label 3 <td>Value 3
</table>
</div>
</html>
```

When I open this page in a browser, I get, not two columns, but the "hint" div taking 100% of the width, and below that the "form" div taking 100% of the width. If I change both the max-width's to "width: 50%", I get two columns as I would expect. Apparently I'm missing something about how max-width is supposed to work, but ... I don't get it.

Comment: With the info you've given, your problem shouldn't exist. Perhaps you could us a link to an example so we can see it happening in the wild.

Comment: I opened your example code in FF3.5.3 on a Mac and PC and it worked just fine. I do get the behavior you're describing in IE 7, and don't have 8 to test with.

Comment: @Emily: I only tried the example above with IE 8 before posting it. I'll take your word on it that it works with Firefox. But I tried other, similar examples that failed similarly with Firefox, so apparently they're not totally immune to the root cause here. In any case, I really want something that works with at least IE 7, IE 8, and Firefox 3, as those are probably the most popular browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

max-width on IE8 is buggy under multiple scenarios. It is a known issue.

You can find an article on it here. http://edskes.net/ie8overflowandexpandingboxbugs.htm

You need three things to trigger this bug - maxwidth, scrollbars, and float

Comment: as seanmonstar said, you need to be weary of the outter elements too. In the old days (ie-7), if you had a width of 100%, it expanded as far as it could. In the new days, elements have a default value of nothing, which means you need every surrounding element to have a width of 100% too; it's not assumed.

Comment: I think the bug occurs in more situations than that post indicates because I've gotten it, for example, trying to do those with a two-column table rather than using float. But thanks: Knowing it's a known bug and not just that I'm going crazy doesn't solve the problem, but at least tells me to look for a totally different solution.

Comment: @Diadem: I did try tinkering with setting the width of the parent element to 100% in one of my test cases and it didn't help. It's certainly possible that with the right combination of settings it would work and I just didn't hit on that. Ah well, I think I'm going to abandon max-width until new browser versions come out.

Comment: @Jay: There's a cheat fix for IE8. All you have to do is add the following code to your head tag before your title - 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />

That will make all ie8 pages behave mostly like IE7 and should remove problems like the one you are having entirely. It won't do much for the firefox issue, but it will make your life easier. There are some native IE8 style bugs that are so bad that they'll crash the entire browser.

Answer (score 5):

Max-width works perfectly fine in FF3 and IE8 with percentages. Percentages, however, are based off the parent width. Not children around it.

Comment: For best results, ensure that the parent width is a static value.

Comment: Children around it? This doesn't really make sense... Do you mean siblings?

Answer (score 1):

If you were to float the div.hint and form both to the left and have them both with a max-width of 50%, they shouldn't squish each other.

```
<div>
  <div class="form" style="float:left; max-width:50%">
    <form></form>
  </div>
  <div class="hint" style="float:left; max-width:50%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, I tried that. And the first div gets 100% of the screen width and comes on top; the second div comes underneath with 100% of the screen width. It's like the max-width is completely ignored. If I change "max-width" to "width", then it works, except of course that then the widths are fixed rather than being variable.